# Need help to correctly setup ssl for lua

Tags: windows, websocket, lua, openssl, luarocks

It's now been several days I mess with Lua to make a node.js server connecting to it via WebSockets. Despite the pain I got as I really never touched Lua before, I managed to do a lot of progress, but now, I'm stuck.
I'm trying to install lua-http with luarocks. I managed to install all dependencies but 2 and I just don't get what to do for them. Those are cqueues and luaossl.
When I tried to install them separately, I noticed they both need some ssl files, and this is where I got in lot of trouble. I installed SSL via OpenSSL, and I also downloaded the source so it can get the includes, but there are files I can't find, and I even never heard of before (although I learned what they exactly are during my researches, I couldn't get more about them)

I'm currently stuck there:

```
> luarocks install cqueues CRYPTO_INCDIR=C:\external\include CRYPTO_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"
Installing https://luarocks.org/cqueues-20200726.54-0.src.rock

Error: Could not find library file for CRYPTO
  No file libcrypto.dll.a in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file crypto.dll.a in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file libcrypto.a in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file cygcrypto.dll in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file libcrypto.dll in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file crypto.dll in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
  No file crypto.lib in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
You may have to install CRYPTO in your system and/or pass CRYPTO_DIR or CRYPTO_LIBDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install cqueues CRYPTO_DIR=/usr/local
```

So I'm here to call for help. Thank you very much!